# forward remote tcp port to local port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tcp, port-forwarding

I have the following setup:
[image: setup diagram]

The unit constantly tries to connect to the Remote Server on a specific known port.
On the Remote Server, there is nothing but open TCP ports.
I want to forward the Remote Server's port to My Pc and open a TCP Server to read the data.
Eventually, I want to use Python to implement this,
but in the meantime, I'm trying to use ssh to do this: `ssh -N -R 10000:localhost:10000 username@hostname`,
and on my side (My Pc), I tried to open a socket (with python) to listen to port 10000, and tried to open [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) to simulate a TCP server, however, I didn't receive any data.

obviously, something is missing, what is it?
p.s. opening a TCP server on the Remote Server will get the data,
but I need to control the connections from My Pc.

Comment: Why not simply do DNAT with iptables?

Comment: because there might be multiple units (each unit would have a different port number), and I want to control the ports that I want to listen to from (My Pc), however, I need to learn about `DNAT with iptables`, maybe this is a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts about [`-R` in `ssh`'s man page](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#R):

> `-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`
>
> [...]
>
> By default, **TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the
> loopback interface only**. This **may be overridden by specifying a
> bind_address**. An **empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’**, indicates
> that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. **Specifying a
> remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's `GatewayPorts`
> option is enabled (see [`sshd_config(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#GatewayPorts)).**

The listening socket on the remote server listens only on *localhost* so connections from UNIT are rejected (ie: it's "closed").

So if the server already allows it, just using this would work:

```
ssh -N -R :10000:localhost:10000 username@hostname
```

Note the additional `:` to have "an empty bind_address" before it (the actual Remote Server's UNIT-facing IP address could also be used instead). This should be improved into:

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -R :10000:localhost:10000 username@hostname
```

to prevent mistakenly running it twice.

But using this type of bind address is usually not allowed by default, Remote Server's *sshd* configuration for [`GatewayPorts`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#GatewayPorts) should be changed. On the Remote Server, the configuration file, usually `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, should be amended to have an (uncommented) entry like this:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

and the ssh daemon should be reloaded to use its new configuration.

Comment: if this would work, when I ssh the host (`Remote Server`) and exe the cmd who, should I see two entries?

Comment: You did specify `-N`: no remote command. So I doubt it. What you should do on remote server is use netstat. That should be `netstat -an | grep -w 10000` or if it's running Linux you can use `ss -atn sport == 10000`.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can start by confirming you did the two actions I wrote in my question, especially changing the server's configuration. Also if your local python process isn't running, UNIT's attempt will abort immediately and no ongoing connection will be seen.

Comment: And last but not least: adding a `-v` option to the `ssh` command will tell when the tunnel has been used (eg it would display a few lines, the 2nd one being: `debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen  port 10000, originator UNIT-ip-address port XXXXX`)

Comment: you almost solved it for me, it worked for me only when I executed the following command: `ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -R hostname:10000:127.0.0.1:10000 username@hostname`, don't ask me why, but it worked :), therefore, thanks a lot :))